# Topic that publishes Current Pose of TurtleBot

Tags: navigation, pose, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a topic that publishes the current pose of the turtlebot?

robot_pose_ekf/odom doesn't give the pose relative to the global frame.
amcl_pose doesn't give the pose when the robot is stationary.

What should I do to get the robot pose when the robot is stationary? Should I get the value from robot_pose_ekf/odom and then use the transform from /odom to /map as given by the /tf topic???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30648/topic-that-publishes-current-pose-of-turtlebot/) by [prasanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/1968/prasanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would help us if you could also identify the goal of seeing this information. If you're trying to see this information in a terminal, you can use:

```
rosrun tf view_frames /map /odom
```

or

```
rosrun tf view_frames /map /base_link
```

If you're trying to do this in code, you can perform this lookup in code as well.

```
  // Look up transform between base link and the map frame.
  tf::StampedTransform xform;
  try
  {
    // The waypoint frame is the source frame
    tf_.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), xform);
  }
  catch (tf::TransformException ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3